# UITableView in UITableViewControllers row-dividers off?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got my custom UITableViewCell working now, with 'dynamic' height using Auto Layouts.

However, these row-dividers are kind of off.

It's a UITableViewController. The width of the image is the full width of the iPhone in the simulator.

Anyone have a clue? It's kind of a UITableViewController right of the shelf, not much code in it, mostly code for datasource/delegation.

**To clearify** I want the separators, but I want them equally indented on both sides. The default indention is fine, which is on the left side, but not the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fogmeister mentioned, you could remove the separators entirely and just add a separator view on your custom table cells or you could extend the separators by setting the

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

note that this is only available for iOS 8 onwards.

Comment: Thank you, this solution I'm OK with (that it spans the full width). However, something is still abit strange. If i set `cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)` for example, I get 10px indention on the left side, but 0 on the right. Which still suggests that something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

These are called separators.

You can turned them off in Interface Builder as a property on the tableView.

Select the tableview and select the "None" property for the separator.

Comment: I want them there. It's just that I want them equally indented.

Answer (score 0):

The default for the UITableViewCell separators is to be indented.  However, by digging into your UITableViewCell's subviews, you can move and size the separator by altering its frame.

In your custom UITableViewCell class, override the layoutSubviews() method so you can grab the separator object as the cell's subviews are being laid out by iterating through your cell's subviews and check for a subview of the UITableViewCellSeparator type.  If you want to make the separator span the entire cell's width, for example, change its frame's origin.x to 0 and make the separator the full width of the cell's contentView.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    for subview in self.subviews {
        if subview.dynamicType == NSClassFromString("_UITableViewCellSeparatorView") {
            var newFrame = subview.frame
            newFrame.origin.x = 0
            newFrame.size.width = self.contentView.frame.width
            separator.frame = newFrame
        }
    }
}
```